# install4j can we customizing the location of storage of user inputs

Tags: install4j

I see in install4j on update installation, the user is presented with the options/data that they provided during the fresh installation.

From where the installer is picking up this data?(Is it doing it from the response.varfile)

Is there way that we can customize the file/location from where installer will pickup this information? (I read that it can be stored in a different file. My concern is that new location will be picked up by the installer on re-run/update or not)

Can the user modify this data and will the installer act according to the modifications?

How is the protected data (like passwords) stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there way that we can customize the file/location from where installer will pickup this information?

By default, the file is always located under `.install4j/response.varfile`. You could specify another response file path on the "Load a response file" action in both the installer and the uninstaller, but then you have to add a "Create a response file" action on the "Finish" screen to save it to that file. The default response file will always be written in any case.

Also, you can specify `-varfile [file]` on the command line to read another response file.

> Can the user modify this data and will the installer act according to the modifications?

Yes.

> How is the protected data (like passwords) stored?

Only response file variables are stored. They have to be bound to form components or you explicitly call `context.registerResponseFileVariable(...)` for a variable name.

To prevent a variable from being logged anywhere, call `context.registerHiddenVariable(...)` for a variable name.

Those settings are also available in the GUI, if you pre-define installer variables on the "Installer variables" tab of the "Installer" node.

The "Password" form component will not write its bound variable to the response file by default and it also configures that variable as a hidden variable automatically. If you select the "Write encoded value to response file" property of the "Password" form component an obfuscated, but non-secure value is written to the response file.

For more on response files, see the [documentation](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/installers/responseFile.html).